# How to find probability in an exponential distribution problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

A student bought a calculator for study purposes. It is assumed that the time 
to failure of a calculator has an exponential distribution with the mean three years. In addition it is given that if the purchased calculator survives the warranty period of two years, then what is the probability that it will survive the next year also?

My Attempt:

I used the memoryless property here.

$P(X>2) = \int_2^\infty3e^{-3x}dx$
which gives the answer $e^{-6}$. But the answer I am getting is wrong according to the exercise. Kindly help me where I am doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The rate is $\frac{1}{3}$, not $3$.

Comment: @BrianTung oh my mistake... thanks .... still answer is not coming right.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what's not coming right for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of an exponential distribution is the inverse of the rate.   $$X\sim\mathcal{Exp}(\lambda) ~\implies~ \mathsf E(X)=\lambda^{-1}$$

Thus, for a mean of $3$years, the rate you should be using is $\tfrac 13\mathrm{years}^{-1}$.

Additionally, should be seeking (thanks to the memoryless property):
$$\mathsf P(X > 3\mid X>2) = \mathsf P(X> 1)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I got it now.